# Copy oracle Instant Client zip files from src folder to docker image

Tags: docker, node-oracledb

I want to know if I can copy the Instant Client zip files from my project src folder to the docker image when it is created. I don't have access to the machine where docker runs so I'd like to know if this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This question was cross posted to https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues/1230).

The answer is yes.

See https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html#docker and https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/docker-for-oracle-database-applications-in-nodejs-and-python-part-1